# T-SQL return rows with unique field

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've got the following CTE expression:

```
WITH DocDetails_CTE 
 AS
(
SELECT   d.DocumentId,    
         dd.AutUser,           
        rank() over (order by d.DocumentId) as [r]
  FROM   Document d
         INNER JOIN DocumentItems di
                 ON d.DocumentId = di.DocumentId           
         INNER JOIN DocumentDetails dd
                 ON dd.DocumentDetailsId = di.DocDetailsId           
  )
  SELECT *
  FROM DocDetails_CTE
```

Which returns the following results:

```
documentId| AuthUser |      [r]
-------------------------------
52  Derck       1
52  John        1
53  Niall       3
53  Bill        3
53  John        3
53  Andy        3
54  Rob         7
54  Noel        7
```

How can I modify the CTE so that I only get the first row which has a new documentId 
e.g.

```
documentId| AuthUser |      [r]
-------------------------------
52  Derck       1    
53  Niall       3
54  Rob         7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to decide what "first row" means - by crafting a `min` or `max` or some other way to identify the row you wanted.  This would return the "first" alphabetically:-

```
select cte.DocumentId, min(cte.AutUser) as AutUser, cte.[r]
from (
  SELECT   d.DocumentId,    
             dd.AutUser,           
            rank() over (order by d.DocumentId) as [r]
      FROM   Document d
             INNER JOIN DocumentItems di
                     ON d.DocumentId = di.DocumentId           
             INNER JOIN DocumentDetails dd
                     ON dd.DocumentDetailsId = di.DocDetailsId

) cte
group by cte.DocumentId, cte.[r]
```

or you can nest two windowed functions and reproduce your (potentially) random code:-

```
select
    pass2.documentid, 
    pass2.autuser, 
    pass2.r
from (
    select
        pass1.*,
        row_number() over (partition by [r] order by documentid ) as rownumber
    from (
        select
            d.documentid,
            dd.autuser,
            rank() over (order by d.documentid) as [r]
        from document d
        join documentitems di on di.documentid = d.documentid           
        join documentdetails dd on dd.documentdetailsid = di.docdetailsid 
    ) pass1
) pass2
where pass2.rownumber=1
```

Comment: I only want to display the row when a new documentId appears, as illustrated above.

Comment: but what does "appear" mean? in your example, why is Derck chosen rather than John for documentId 1?  Why Niall rather than Bill, John and Andy? your code would produce different answers depending on clustered index keys and table statistics that caused different execution plans to be adopted by the query optimizer. You would normally want to protect yourself from this type of "random" behaviour which is difficult to spot when debugging.

Comment: thanks for the detailed reply, yes i want to return one row only for each documentId. so for documentId 52 i want either john or  Derck - but not both. I need to get 1 row for each documentId. thanks

Comment: yes the second solution works perfect as it eliminates the need for a CTE. fair play.- thanks.